# Functional Bean Definition and Spring Boot: How to migrate integration tests?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-webflux

I migrated a microservice (with Spring Boot and Kotlin) from annotation-based beans to "Functional Bean Definition" DSL. Basically I'm having the following code which works fine:

```
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
class Application

val beans = beans {
    bean<CustomerService>()
    bean<CustomerHandler>()
    bean(::router)
    ...
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<Application>(*args) {
        addInitializers(beans)
    }
}
```

However, I cannot find any information how to migrate the integration tests (with JUnit 5) using the functional beans having a code fragment as below. Any hint is appreciated!

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension::class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = RANDOM_PORT)
@TestPropertySource(locations = ["/rest-test.properties"])
class CustomerRestTest(@LocalServerPort private val port: Int) {...}
```

Comment: And why would you need to change your test? That should still remain the same, the fact that you changed your configuration doesn't, at runtime, change how your request is being handled.

Comment: When using "Functional Bean Definition" the integration tests don't work anymore because the app's beans are not available. I'll wait until Spring Kofu (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-fu) is more stable.

Comment: The main issue is that in your `main` method you are adding an `ApplicationContextInitializer` to add the Kotlin defined beans. This isn't done in the tests as that doesn't execute your `main` method. What propbaly would work is to let your `Application` class implement `ApplicationContextInitializer` and in the `initialize` method handle the bean registration, this should also work for integration tests.

Comment: Indeed, I was also thinking about this workaround. However, it remains a workaround and I prefer to wait for Spring Kofu.

Comment: It isn't so much a workaround as you are doing the same in the `main` method of the application. But as the `main` method isn't invoked in the test this isn't done in the initializing code for the tests.

Comment: Isn't this what `@FunctionalSpringBootTest ` is made for?